# How can I use ES6 in Function?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

```
const funcs = {
            Edit(productBomId) { console.log(productBomId); }, 
            Delete(productBomId) { console.log(productBomId); }
    }

    export default funcs

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Edit(1);">Edit<a/>
```

I have use es6 javascript and i'm trying to function call but thorw error.
error is below

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Edit is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

Comment: `Object.assign(window, funcs)`

Answer (score 1):

```
funcs.Edit(1)
```

You created an object called `funcs` with two methods.

Comment: not working . now this error throw Uncaught ReferenceError: funcs is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: @KrimeshRaiyani: Then you didn't define `funcs` globally, or you're trying to use it from another module but didn't import it properly, or something. You gave very little code in your question, so if you want a complete answer, give a complete demonstration of the problem.

Comment: plz send me example